# Writing a RESTful service using WCF for public usage. Is providing WSDL really necessary?

Tags: wcf, rest, wsdl

As the question suggests, is providing the WSDL really necessary, or is it more of a "nice to have" feature?  I have written a RESTful service, using .Net 4.0.  I see now that WSDL isn't automatically generated by adding ?wsdl... and I can't get it to either after trying various suggestions :-/

I have written several ASMX services in the past - all well and good as the WSDL is accessible automatically.  I want to move away from SOAP.  I would prefer to provide potential users with a Class (C#, Java versions etc..) and sample code.  Is that an equally viable option?  Or am I being lazy in suggesting all that?

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: WSDL is primarily for SOAP services - REST is not SOAP. REST has its own format (WADL) but that's not nearly as relevant as WSDL is for SOAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WSDL = SOAP;

REST != WSDL;
```

For a REST Service, WSDL is **not** a *nice-to-have* it is a *cannot-have*.

If you are exposing a RESTful service then WSDL does not mean anything - WSDL means you have a SOAP web service.

You can expose a SOAP web service in addition to your REST service but the WSDL would be for that service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this may be more personal opinion, but do you think I should bother offering SOAP? It is generally new apps that will consume the service, so I'm thinking of just leaving it as is and not bothering with a SOAP implementation.

Comment: It is a good question. You could and sometimes you must if your customers need it. If you keep operations in the services thin and keep all the logic in the lower layers (business layer) then exposing a SOAP service is trivial.